# error in saving data on _User classname Parse Swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform, save

it states that classname should not start in underscore but when i use User only instead of _User it creates new class name User on parse any one who encounter this?

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid class name. Class names cannot start with an underscore.

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid class name. Class names cannot start with an underscore.

Comment: Are you using a `PFObject` instead of `PFUser`?